# Issue in updating document title in next js 14

Tags: next.js, next.js13

As per the documentation(https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#generatemetadata-function) I tried to update the document title using the following function.

```js
export async function generateMetadata(props: PageProps) {
    return {
        title: {
            absolute: 'My new page title',
        },
    };
}

// My page component goes here
```

The title is updating but as soon as the page gets hydrated it's getting replaced by the default title(one that I've set in layout.tsx)

Updating the title from the client with useEffect seems working. But then what's the use of next js  generateMetadata function??

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    document.title="New title"
},[])
```

Comment: can u update the question providing the metadata object you have defined in the layout.tsx